# How to align social icons in footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two `<ul>` tags with links to pages and links to social icons. How ever they are not aligned when I created second `<ul>` tag to have social icons like this:

Here's my site: https://bgrnature.herokuapp.com/#/contact-us

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="about-us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="faqs">FAQS</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="contact-us">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right footer-icons">
                <li><a href="" class="inactiveLink">Copyright © 2016 </a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Applying padding-bottom or margin-top is not effective at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: The icon `<i>` should be inside `<a>` I think, please also post relevant css code.

Comment: margin-top on social-icons li works - <li style="margin-top:15px" ><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-inverse"

Comment: @Naga Sai A yeah after placing `<i>` inside `<a>` as @Pangloss said and then applying `margin-top` as you said worked. Thankyou

Comment: @Satyadev, without modifying your exiting code, i have provided codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NrpGzL in which i have created one class for social icons and gave margin-top:15px

Comment: @NagaSaiA strange..When I tried `magin-top` or `margin-bottom` it didn't work so I posted the question. anyway thank you

Comment: @Satyadev on footer * is getting applied to complete footer elements , so it appears like not aligned ,creating separate class gives you control social icons position

Comment: adding only `margin-top:15px` will effect the hover affect on social icons :)
you need to put the icons inside `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create class for the li's of the social icons and give margin-top:15px

```
.social{
  margin-top:15px;
}
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NrpGzL

Answer (score 1):

Please put the `i` inside `a` and also give `.social` class some `margin`.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right footer-icons">
            <li><a href="" class="inactiveLink">Copyright © 2016 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.social{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```